# Neo4j configurations required for big data

Tags: php, performance, configuration, neo4j

I know database queries needs be written considering performance. Though server configurations should be used for supporting maximum performance.

My database is having:

1. 10 million nodes
2. 30 million relationships
3. 30 label types
4. 100 relationship types

I read though [performance guide of Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/performance-guide.html). But it is hard to find best required server settings in Neo4j. So my question is:

What are the minimal server configurations and Neo4j configurations should have for good performance (i.e less response time) from Neo4j?

1. Considering 10k concurrent connections
2. Ratio of Read:Write is 90:10
3. Scripting Language is PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your graph is not very big, the concurrent users are more interesting.
I recommend a Neo4j cluster with one master that you send writes to and a number of slaves (3-4) for the reads.

I had good experiences with these boxes with 128G RAM and 12 CPUs and 500G SSD for 140 bucks a month.

https://www.hetzner.de/us/hosting/produkte_rootserver/px120ssd

The [Neoclient](http://www.neoxygen.io/components) driver is a pretty good choice also with support for HA servers.

Comment: Could you please give me Neo4j db configurations required for this type of data?